# cancel form post if server takes too long to respond

Tags: javascript, html, http

I am maintaining a legacy web application that has a form to make queries against a server. That form, when posted, depending on the input values, may cause the server to  take a lot of time to respond.

So I added a modal dialog with a nice animation that  grays out the rest of the screen and asks the user to wait until his query is finished on the server. Now UX wants me to add a cancel button to that dialog that will return the user to the previous state (before the form was posted) and I am told to "simply" ignore what the server does (so there is no expectation to cancel the job on the server side). Effectively this is just a nice animation that the user sees while the results page gets prepared by the server and send to the browser. I can dismiss the modal dialog all right; the problem is that when the browser does receives the server's response it automatically navigates to the results page even though the user thought they "cancelled" the query.

Am I right in thinking that what is being asked cannot be implemented in the traditional form submit / navigate to a new page way?

I know how to accomplish this with Ajax so the question is whether I can somehow cancel the navigation to the results page, after the form has been posted using a synchronous / traditional model.

Comment: I agree with you. I don't believe this is a functionality the browser exposes nor in your control (as far as the traditional form submit action is concerned). The browser is handling the submit event natively and you have no means to interject. I would love to find out if someone disagrees though

Comment: Yeah, once it's gone through, it's gone through.